# How to make my own video view counter in an efficient way?

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I am developing a website that have so many videos.Now I am  facing  a problem that how to make my own video view counter . I know a simple way :

```
UPDATE view_counter_table SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE video_id = ‘$video_id’;
```

But problem is that I don’t think this is an efficient way to make a view counter for my website. Because suppose a video is viewed 50K times, at the same time there are so many videos people watching at the same rate , which means so many update instructions. This could be a cause of system overload and bandwidth overhead .In addition this may cause of my website  crash(in extreme case).

Now, I want suggestion , is it efficient way to use the update instruction(given above) or there are some other ways to create a view counter that will reduce overhead. (Such as , *9gag.tv* uses it’s own video view counter , seems like it’s view counter is  efficient and faster)    .

Comment: If you're really concerned about speed, try [Redis](http://redis.io/). MySQL can do the job up to a point, and then it starts to bog down, though we're talking 10-20 requests per second or more on an untuned server before you have that problem. A properly tuned server can handle hundreds per second. Redis can handle thousands to hundreds of thousands.

Comment: this is failing you `‘$video_id’` if it's part of your real code.